# Bindings between controller and factory in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, timeout

I would like to understand how bindings are working in angularJS.
I tried to create code as simply as possible to show you mu problem. 
I know how to use this but I don't how It works.

Here is my example. In it I have 3 scope variables: 
 [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rBJl6KK6DEjwX0em68Pk?p=preview)

```
<pre>{{A}}</pre>
<pre>{{B}}</pre>
<pre>{{C()}}</pre>
```

These are defined as follows:

```
  $scope.A = factory;
  $scope.B = factory.a;
  $scope.C = function() {
    return factory.a.b;
  };
```

factory named "factory" returns this object:

```
    a: {'b': 'foo'}
```

Timeout updates factory this way:

```
  $timeout(function() {
    factory.a = {
      'b': 'BOO'
    }
  }, 1000);
```

I would like to ask if any one can give me clear answer why only first (A) and third (C) are updating after timeout but not second one.

Comment: The B is a collection (object) in Angular. Values and functions will update on digest, object attributes won't be detected during "dirty"  checking.

Answer (score 0):

**Case B** doesn't change because `$scope.B` doesn't change.

```
  factory.a = {b: 'foo'};
  $scope.B = factory.a;

  $timeout(function() {
    factory.a = {'b': 'BOO'};
  }, 1000);
```

When the `$timeout` function changes `factory.a`,  `$scope.B` still points to the previous object, `{b: 'foo'}`.

---

**Case A** changes because the *contents* of `$scope.A` changes.

```
  $scope.A = factory;
```

Even though the object *reference* named `factory` doesn't change, the *contents* of the reference changes.

---

**Case C** changes because the function's return value changes.

```
  $scope.C = function() {
    return factory.a.b;
  };
```

Every digest cycle, the AngularJS framework evaluates the function and updates the DOM with any change.

Comment: "When the $timeout function changes factory.a,  $scope.B still points to the previous object, {b: 'foo'}." - but why?